# How to remove "just the selection color" on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know how to remove selection color from `UITableViewCell` with

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

But it disable all "on press" response from view inside it... Is there any way to remove just the selection color?

Best regards,

Comment: what you want exactly ?

Comment: My cell have an UIImageView as background covering almost all the UITableViewCell. I set the `image` and `highlighted` on IB, it respond as I expected, but the selection color still visible on the uncovered part. If I use `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`, the imageView does not respond to highlighted state.

Comment: You need to give more info because something else is wrong. `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` does exactly what you need.

Comment: try cell.SelectedBackgroundView  instead of highlighted

Comment: @Pratik: Somehow that give me the right direction and I solve the problem. I post it on answer.

Comment: @Desdenova : `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` does the trick, but it also remove the selected state on all of view in the cell.

Comment: I think you could override the setHighlighted:animated: method and force the highlighted state for your imageView after calling supers.

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo : I already post the answer that solve my problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer based on Pratik comment. Use this code to remove just the selection color.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```